# _sppagecontext.userEmail does not return email ID for all users. how to configure it in Sharepoint online and 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

_sppagecontext.userEmail does not return email ID for all users.
for some users _spPageContextInfo.userLoginNam is needed.

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint Online, user login name and userEmail should be the same and will be:
username@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com

[image]

For SharePoint On-Premise, _spPageContextInfo only provide userId property, for email and Loginname:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;

function GetCurrentUser() {
var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";

var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };

$.ajax({
  url : requestUri,
  contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
  headers : requestHeaders,
  success : onSuccess,
  error : onError
});
}

function onSuccess(data, request){
  console.log(data.d);
  var loginName = data.d.LoginName;
  var email=data.d.Email;
  alert(loginName);
  alert(email);
}

function onError(error) {
  alert(error);
}

GetCurrentUser();

});
</script>
```

Make sure the work email in current user profile is not empty.